# Combining two 16 bits RGB colors with alpha blending

Tags: c, colors, alphablending

I have a TFT display which can draw 16 bit colors, format RGB 565. I would like to add some transparency to what I display on it.

Let's say I have a black background (0x0000) and I want to draw a white foreground (0xFFFF) that is half transparent (opacity is controlled by another byte), so it will appear grey. How do I calculate that 16 bit grey color in the same RGB 565 format so I can send it to my TFT and it will display correctly (probably with some loss but I don't care)?

I need a function such as:

```
unsigned short calcColor_RGB565(unsigned short background_RGB565, unsigned short foreground_RGB565, unsigned char opacity)
```

`calcColor_RGB565(0x0000, 0xFFFF, 128)` would result 0x8410 (or 0x1084, it isn't important because I send two separate bytes to the TFT so I would just invert the order if needed)

Thanks to anyone who can help me, I have tried things but I can't get the correct result not even close :/.

C-like pseudo code appreciated but I prefer explanations on how to do it.

Edit: forgot to say, I would like it to be as fast as possible because it's for an old microprocessor, so if it's faster to calculate the 2 bytes separately (and so I also don't have to separate them later) then I'm highly interested in such optimisations.

Edit 27 September: 5 days later, still not solved. I can convert from rgb565 to rgb8888, do the alpha blending and then convert back to rgb565, but that is too slow, there must be a better way!

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: My current code was originally copied from this: https://developers.sifteo.com/docs/SifteoSDK/1.0.0/color_8h_source.html but that lerp function didn't give the correct result so I tried modify things but couldn't do better result...I am beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My (untested) solution: I split the foreground and background colors to (red + blue) and (green) components and multiply them with a 6bit alpha value. Enjoy! (Only if it works :)

```
                            //   rrrrrggggggbbbbb
#define MASK_RB       63519 // 0b1111100000011111
#define MASK_G         2016 // 0b0000011111100000
#define MASK_MUL_RB 4065216 // 0b1111100000011111000000
#define MASK_MUL_G   129024 // 0b0000011111100000000000
#define MAX_ALPHA        64 // 6bits+1 with rounding

uint16 alphablend( uint16 fg, uint16 bg, uint8 alpha ){

  // alpha for foreground multiplication
  // convert from 8bit to (6bit+1) with rounding
  // will be in [0..64] inclusive
  alpha = ( alpha + 2 ) >> 2;
  // "beta" for background multiplication; (6bit+1);
  // will be in [0..64] inclusive
  uint8 beta = MAX_ALPHA - alpha;
  // so (0..64)*alpha + (0..64)*beta always in 0..64

  return (uint16)((
            (  ( alpha * (uint32)( fg & MASK_RB )
                + beta * (uint32)( bg & MASK_RB )
            ) & MASK_MUL_RB )
          |
            (  ( alpha * ( fg & MASK_G )
                + beta * ( bg & MASK_G )
            ) & MASK_MUL_G )
         ) >> 6 );
}

/*
  result masks of multiplications
  uppercase: usable bits of multiplications
  RRRRRrrrrrrBBBBBbbbbbb // 5-5 bits of red+blue
        1111100000011111 // from MASK_RB * 1
  1111100000011111000000 //   to MASK_RB * MAX_ALPHA // 22 bits!


  -----GGGGGGgggggg----- // 6 bits of green
        0000011111100000 // from MASK_G * 1
  0000011111100000000000 //   to MASK_G * MAX_ALPHA
*/
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for being late, I have tested your function, and while it gives different results (different rounding errors I guess) compared to Dietrich Epp's one, it is also more than twice faster! I will do some more tests to see which one gives the most accurate colors.. but I think I will use yours anyway. So I set your answer as Best, but both are great answers ;)

Comment: Thanks. My version is the less precise one because it starts by chopping 2 bits from every color :) BTW, I "invented" this 6bit solution here: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/36882 It's a blur function if you happen to need it once.

Comment: looks that the variable `a` means `alpha`, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

The correct formula is something like this:

```
unsigned short blend(unsigned short fg, unsigned short bg, unsigned char alpha)
{
    // Split foreground into components
    unsigned fg_r = fg >> 11;
    unsigned fg_g = (fg >> 5) & ((1u << 6) - 1);
    unsigned fg_b = fg & ((1u << 5) - 1);

    // Split background into components
    unsigned bg_r = bg >> 11;
    unsigned bg_g = (bg >> 5) & ((1u << 6) - 1);
    unsigned bg_b = bg & ((1u << 5) - 1);

    // Alpha blend components
    unsigned out_r = (fg_r * alpha + bg_r * (255 - alpha)) / 255;
    unsigned out_g = (fg_g * alpha + bg_g * (255 - alpha)) / 255;
    unsigned out_b = (fg_b * alpha + bg_b * (255 - alpha)) / 255;

    // Pack result
    return (unsigned short) ((out_r << 11) | (out_g << 5) | out_b);
}
```

There is a shortcut you can use for dividing by 255.  The compiler should be able to provide some strength reduction, but you might be able to do better by using the following formula instead:

```
// Alpha blend components
unsigned out_r = fg_r * a + bg_r * (255 - alpha);
unsigned out_g = fg_g * a + bg_g * (255 - alpha);
unsigned out_b = fg_b * a + bg_b * (255 - alpha);
out_r = (out_r + 1 + (out_r >> 8)) >> 8;
out_g = (out_g + 1 + (out_g >> 8)) >> 8;
out_b = (out_b + 1 + (out_b >> 8)) >> 8;
```

Note the large number of variables in the function... this is okay.  If you try to "optimize" the code by rewriting the equations so that it creates fewer temporary variables, you are only doing work that the compiler already does for you.  Unless you have a really bad compiler.

If this is not fast enough, there are a few options for how to proceed.  However, choosing the correct option depends on the results of profiling, how the code is used, and the target architecture.

Comment: Thanks a LOT, I tested and this is working as should, (at least for white on black with half opacity, it gives a grey ;). I guess it doesn't give 0x8410 but 0x7BEF because of precision loss compared to 32bits colors?) Once again, thanks, I will study the code and try to understand it!

Comment: No, 0x7BEF is exactly correct, even if you use 32 bits.  In binary it is 01111 011111 01111, as you can see, each component is exactly equal to 50% full scale, rounding down.

Comment: If you set the alpha to 132 instead of 127, then you will get 10000 100000 10000, which is slightly brighter than 50% gray.  It is somewhat unspecified which direction you would like to round, but it rarely makes any visual difference.

Comment: Result is already "wrong" due to lack of gamma correction; spending more instructions rounding won't make it any more accurate.

Comment: It is strange because I tried in Paint.NET to make a black background 0x000000 with alpha 255 and white foreground 0xFFFFFF with alpha 128, and then used a plugin to export to rgb565, it showed 0x8410 (well, 0x1084 for some reasons...). Then I tried to export to normal bitmap file and use another converter I found online, this one also showed 0x8410. Not saying your code isn't correct but I would like to understand why there is a (tiny) difference, so if you know, please explain ;)

Comment: @user2534317: You are trying to write a 50% level to the buffer, but you have to round either to 51% or 49%.  Which one is correct?  Neither.  Which one has less error?  The error is equal.

Comment: @CoryNelson: The code is correct, if you specify that the inputs and outputs are linear RGB.

Comment: Thanks again Dietrich Epp you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I've found an alternative method which is ~25% faster than biziclop's approximation. This is also an approximation because it reduces the levels of alpha from 0-255 to 0-31 (32 levels of alpha) but it does not truncate color bits as far as I can tell.

Visually on my TFT display the results look the same as those from biziclop's algorithm, but I haven't checked individual pixel values to see what the difference is (if any).

Note that although fg and bg arguments are 32bit unsigned, you must actually just pass in the 16bit RGB565 colors. The 32bit width is required within the function by the algorithm.

```
/**
 * Fast RGB565 pixel blending
 * @param fg      The foreground color in uint16_t RGB565 format
 * @param bg      The background color in uint16_t RGB565 format
 * @param alpha   The alpha in range 0-255
 **/
color alphaBlendRGB565( uint32_t fg, uint32_t bg, uint8_t alpha ){
    alpha = ( alpha + 4 ) >> 3;
    bg = (bg | (bg << 16)) & 0b00000111111000001111100000011111;
    fg = (fg | (fg << 16)) & 0b00000111111000001111100000011111;
    uint32_t result = ((((fg - bg) * alpha) >> 5) + bg) & 0b00000111111000001111100000011111;
    return (uint16_t)((result >> 16) | result);
}
```

I found this solution in a pull request by Chris Chua to the Adafruit Arduino framebuffer libraries. Here is an expanded version with comments to explain the math:

```
// Fast RGB565 pixel blending
// Found in a pull request for the Adafruit framebuffer library. Clever!
// https://github.com/tricorderproject/arducordermini/pull/1/files#diff-d22a481ade4dbb4e41acc4d7c77f683d
color alphaBlendRGB565( uint32_t fg, uint32_t bg, uint8_t alpha ){
    // Alpha converted from [0..255] to [0..31]
    alpha = ( alpha + 4 ) >> 3;

    // Converts  0000000000000000rrrrrggggggbbbbb
    //     into  00000gggggg00000rrrrr000000bbbbb
    // with mask 00000111111000001111100000011111
    // This is useful because it makes space for a parallel fixed-point multiply
    bg = (bg | (bg << 16)) & 0b00000111111000001111100000011111;
    fg = (fg | (fg << 16)) & 0b00000111111000001111100000011111;

    // This implements the linear interpolation formula: result = bg * (1.0 - alpha) + fg * alpha
    // This can be factorized into: result = bg + (fg - bg) * alpha
    // alpha is in Q1.5 format, so 0.0 is represented by 0, and 1.0 is represented by 32
    uint32_t result = (fg - bg) * alpha; // parallel fixed-point multiply of all components
    result >>= 5;
    result += bg;
    result &= 0b00000111111000001111100000011111; // mask out fractional parts
    return (color)((result >> 16) | result); // contract result
}
```

Comment: any idea of why alpha = ( alpha + 4 ) >> 3;  The +4 on a uint_8 with 255 as a very valid possibilty?

Comment: The +4 is required for a more accurate range conversion. Yes, +4 on the 255 (before shifting) is a definite possibility, but for me (gcc) it works fine, so the intermediate result may be stored as a 16 or 32 bit integer?

Answer (score 2):

This one is based on http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bazald/l/api/_s_d_l___r_l_eaccel_8c_source.html

On my RGB565 16_bit device, it produced the cleanest result.

```
COLOUR ALPHA_BLIT16_565(uint32_t fg, uint32_t bg, int8u alpha) {
    // Alpha converted from [0..255] to [0..31]
    uint32_t ALPHA = alpha >> 3;     
    fg = (fg | fg << 16) & 0x07e0f81f;
    bg = (bg | bg << 16) & 0x07e0f81f;
    bg += (fg - bg) * ALPHA >> 5;
    bg &= 0x07e0f81f;
        return (COLOUR)(bg | bg >> 16);
}
```